# Font not initialised

Tags: python

I keep getting the error "Font not initialized" after running my program. Here's the program. I know I'm initializing pygame. I've tried initializing pygame, pygame.font, and and both of them at the same time. I've done everything. I've tried using pygames default fonts as pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115). That didn't work either.

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init
pygame.font.init


display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

car_width = 100
car_height = 100

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('A Bit Racey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load ('racecar.png')
gameOver = pygame.image.load ('gameover.png')

def gO (x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(gameOver, (x,y))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render (text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, font)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    time.sleep(2)
    game_loop()

def crash ():
    message_display('Game Over')

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))

def game_loop():

    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.8)

    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 7
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0


        x += x_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        #thingx, thingy, thinkw, thingh, color)
        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        car (x,y)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
            crash()


        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)


        if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
            print('y crossover')

            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x+car_width > thing_startx and + car_width < thing_startx+thing_width:
                print('x crossover')
                gO (display_width/2 - 145.5, display_height/2-200)
                time.sleep(2)
                game_loop()


        if gameExit == True:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()


        pygame.display.update()    
        clock.tick(45)

game_loop()
pygame.quit ()
quit ()
```

Comment: can't reproduce, don't get any error

Comment: Maybe wrong font path? Or typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just didn't really run `init` function in your snippet.

```
# didn't run function
pygame.init
pygame.font.init
# instead
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
```

Comment: Thanks. I literally started python yesterday and that's the only thing I've written lol. I'll do that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is strange. Really strange. It even does not have any problem in it. You are not calling the function `pygame.init()`. You are evaluating it. You are checking for its existence. Python will raise an exception if the function does not exist BUT it will NOT do anything if it does. To call a function use `<function_name>(<parameters>)`. This. Is. Not. Ruby.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. (I've never written with RUBY but I get what you mean) I should've also stated that I only started writing Python yesterday. Thanks once more.